# I can't access an inherited method outside the constructor method. How can i solve that? TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, es6-class

In TypeScript I can't access an inherited method outside the constructor method

```ts
export class Strategy extends LakshmiBase implements IStrategy{
    memory:Memory;
    public monitors: MonitorType[] = [];
    constructor(_parent:any, _memory:Memory){
        super(_parent)
        this.memory = _memory;
    }
    init(): IStrategy{
        // this.memory.addListener(Memory.buildKey(COIN_PAIR.BTCUSDT, `${TECHNICAL_INDICATORS.RSI}_14`,TIME_INTERVALS._5m), this.update)
        return this;
    }
    getMonitors(): MonitorType[]{
        return this.monitors;
    }
}
```

The children class

```ts
export class StrategyOpenRsi extends Strategy{
    constructor(_parent:any, _memory:Memory){
        super(_parent, _memory);
        this.setMonitors([
            Monitor.keyToMonitorType(Memory.buildKey(COIN_PAIR.BTCUSDT, INDEX_KEYS.LAST_CANDLE,TIME_INTERVALS._1m)),
            Monitor.keyToMonitorType(Memory.buildKey(COIN_PAIR.BTCUSDT, `${TECHNICAL_INDICATORS.RSI}_14`,TIME_INTERVALS._1m)),
            // Monitor.keyToMonitorType(Memory.buildKey(COIN_PAIR.BTCUSDT, INDEX_KEYS.BOOK))
        ])
        // console.log(this.getMonitors())
        
    }
    update(resp: any): void {
        console.log("StrategyOpenRsi", resp.key)
        console.log(this.getMonitors())
        return;
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the `getMonitors` method from the `update` method of the child class.
But I can access it when I call it from the `constructor`.

```
/Users/brunoferraz/Documents/dev/phd/stockstory/back/src/operation/strategy/rsi/StrategyOpenRsi.ts:21
        console.log(this.getMonitors())
                         ^
TypeError: this.getMonitors is not a function
    at Memory.update (/Users/brunoferraz/Documents/dev/phd/stockstory/back/src/operation/strategy/rsi/StrategyOpenRsi.ts:21:26)
    at Memory.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Memory.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Memory.set (/Users/brunoferraz/Documents/dev/phd/stockstory/back/src/core/Memory.ts:26:14)
    at ExchangeManager.memoryUpdateDefault (/Users/brunoferraz/Documents/dev/phd/stockstory/back/src/core/Core.ts:78:25)
    at ExchangeManager.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ExchangeManager.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at ExchangeManager.processChartData (/Users/brunoferraz/Documents/dev/phd/stockstory/back/src/connection/ExchangeManager.ts:183:14)
    at BinanceService.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at BinanceService.emit (node:domain:489:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```